# iOS Swift: Find index for CKRecord in array

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to use the `find` function to get the index of a CKRecord in an array. However I'm running into a problem that I don't understand.

I have two arrays: `notes` and `allNotes`. `notes` is a subset of `allNotes`. I have an item from `notes` and I'm trying to find its index within `allNotes`. As you can see from the output it exists in both arrays, but its only being found in the `notes` array.

```
func removeNoteAtIndexPath(indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let note = tableViewController.notes[indexPath.row]

    if let index = find(allNotes, note) {
        println("Found in allNotes")
    } else {
        println("Not found in allNotes")
    }

    if let index = find(tableViewController.notes, note) {
        println("Found in notes")
    } else {
        println("Not found in notes")
    }

    println(tableViewController.notes[0])
    println(allNotes[0])
}
```

**Console output**

```
Not found in allNotes
Found in notes
<CKRecord: 0x7fb49ad37120; recordType=Note, recordID=E6BD60A1-AB15-4952-84A3-81BDB4DFC961:(_defaultZone:__defaultOwner__), recordChangeTag=i8nh54t3, values={
    Text = "My note";
}>
<CKRecord: 0x7fb49ac31f60; recordType=Note, recordID=E6BD60A1-AB15-4952-84A3-81BDB4DFC961:(_defaultZone:__defaultOwner__), recordChangeTag=i8nh54t3, values={
    Text = "My note";
}>
```

Comment: It looks like it might be because of how `CKRecord` defines "equal".  You have 2 different `CKRecords`, and even though they have the same `recordID`, it seems like they aren't equal (which is how I assume `find` works).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to adapt Equatable protocol to CKRecord like below.

```
extension CKRecord: Equatable {}
public func
==( lhs: CKRecord, rhs: CKRecord ) -> Bool {
    return lhs.recordID.recordName == rhs.recordID.recordName
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I like Satachito's answer better, but this was my initial solution:

```
func findCKRecord(records: [CKRecord], record: CKRecord) -> Int? {
    var index: Int?
    let recordID = record.recordID

    for (i, record) in enumerate(records) {
        let currentRecordID = record.recordID
        if recordID == currentRecordID {
            index = i
        }
    }

    return index
}
```